# regex replace parts/groups of a string in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub, capture-group

Trying to postprocess the LaTeX (`pdf_book` output) of a bookdown document to collapse biblatex citations to be able to sort them chronologically using `\usepackage[sortcites]{biblatex}` later on. Thus, I need to find `}{` after `\\autocites` and replace it with `,`. I am experimenting with `gsub()` but can't find the correct incantation.

```
# example input
testcase <- "text \\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000}{wattPattern1947}{runkleGap1990} text {keep}{separate}"

# desired output
"text \\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000,wattPattern1947,runkleGap1990} text {keep}{separate}"
```

A simple approach was to replace all `}{`

```
> gsub('\\}\\{', ',', testcase, perl=TRUE)
[1] "text \\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000,wattPattern1947,runkleGap1990} text {keep,separate}"
```

But this also collapses `{keep}{separate}`.

I was then trying to replace `}{` within a 'word' (string of characters without whitspace) starting with `\\autocites` by using different groups and failed bitterly:

```
> gsub('(\\\\autocites)([^ \f\n\r\t\v}{}]+)((\\}\\{})+)', '\\1\\2\\3', testcase, perl=TRUE)
[1] "text \\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000}{wattPattern1947}{runkleGap1990} some text {keep}{separate}"
```

**Addendum**:
The actual document contains more lines/elements than the testcase above. Not all elements contain `\\autocites` and in rare cases one element has more than one `\\autocites`. I didn't originally think this was relevant. A more realistic testcase:

```
testcase2 <- c("some text",
"text \\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000}{wattPattern1947}{runkleGap1990} text {keep}{separate}",
"text \\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000}{wattPattern1947}{runkleGap1990} text {keep}{separate} \\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000}{wattPattern1947}")
```

Comment: the additional "\\autocites" segments should be edited likewise ?

Comment: yes, all '}{' need to be be converted to ',' until whitespace for all '\\autocites'-strings

Comment: Then unglue won't work, I suggest accepting Wiktor's solution if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single `gsub` call is enough:

```
gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|\\\\autocites)\\S*?\\K}{", ",", testcase, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "text \\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000,wattPattern1947,runkleGap1990} text {keep}{separate}"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vs9KIj/1). Here, `(?:\G(?!^)|\\autocites)` matches the end of the previous match or `\autocites` string, then it matches any 0 or more non-whitespace chars, but as few as possible, then `\K` discards the text from the current match buffer and consumes the `}{` substring that is eventually replaced with a comma.

There is also a very readable solution with one regex and one fixed text replacements using `stringr::str_replace_all`:

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(testcase, "\\\\autocites\\S+", function(x) gsub("}{", ",", x, fixed=TRUE))
# => [1] "text \\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000,wattPattern1947,runkleGap1990} text {keep}{separate}"
```

Here, `\\autocites\S+` matches `\autocites` and then 1+ non-whitespace chars, and `gsub("}{", ",", x, fixed=TRUE)` replaces (very fast) each `}{` with `,` in the matched text.

Comment: impressive! and it works also for the new testcase2.

Comment: your 'gsub' solution is by far the fastest. The 'while-length-grep' approach is about 4 times slower and 'str_replace_all()' is about 20 times slower (benchmarked using testcase2).

Comment: Wasn't familiar with `\G` and `\K`. Thanks! Can you please explain the purpose of the negative lookahead after the \G?

Comment: @iod [`\G` operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) matches two positions: 1) start of string and 2) end of the previous successful match. By adding `(?!^)` (or `(?<!^)` / `(?<!\A)` / `(?!\A)`) the start of string position is excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest solution, but it works.  This repeatedly replaces }{ with , but only if it follows autocities with no intervening blanks.

```
while(length(grep('(autocites\\S*)\\}\\{', testcase, perl=TRUE))) {
    testcase = sub('(autocites\\S*)\\}\\{', '\\1,', testcase, perl=TRUE)
}

testcase
[1] "text \\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000,wattPattern1947,runkleGap1990} text {keep}{separate}"
```

Comment: your solution works great. and it also handles testcase2 well.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make the input string slightly bigger to make the algorithm more clear.

```r
str <- "
text \\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000}{wattPattern1947}{runkleGap1990} text {keep}{separate}
text \\autocites[cf.~][]{wattPattern1947}{foxMapping2000}{runkleGap1990} text {keep}{separate}
"
```

We will firstly extract all the citation blocks, replace `"}{"` with `","` in them and then put them back into the string.

```r
# pattern for matching citation blocks
pattern <- "\\\\autocites(\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\])*(\\{[[:alnum:]]*\\})+"
cit <- str_extract_all(str, pattern)[[1]]
cit

#> [1] "\\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000}{wattPattern1947}{runkleGap1990}"
#> [2] "\\autocites[cf.~][]{wattPattern1947}{foxMapping2000}{runkleGap1990}"
```

Replace in citation blocks:

```r
newcit <- str_replace_all(cit, "\\}\\{", ",")
newcit
#> [1] "\\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000,wattPattern1947,runkleGap1990}"
#> [2] "\\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000,wattPattern1947,runkleGap1990}"
```

Break the original string in the places where citation block was found

```r
strspl <- str_split(str, pattern)[[1]]
strspl
#> [1] "\ntext "  " text {keep}{separate}\ntext "  " text {keep}{separate}\n"
```

Insert modified citation blocks:

```r
combined <- character(length(strspl) + length(newcit))
combined[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- strspl
combined[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- newcit
combined
#> [1] "\ntext "                                                          
#> [2] "\\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000,wattPattern1947,runkleGap1990}"
#> [3] " text {keep}{separate}\ntext "                                    
#> [4] "\\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000,wattPattern1947,runkleGap1990}"
#> [5] " text {keep}{separate}\n"
```

Paste it together to finalize:

```r
newstr <- paste(combined, collapse = "")
newstr
#> [1] "\ntext \\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000,wattPattern1947,runkleGap1990} text {keep}{separate}\ntext \\autocites[cf.~][]{foxMapping2000,wattPattern1947,runkleGap1990} text {keep}{separate}\n"
```

I suspect there could be a more elegant fully-regex solution based on the same idea, but I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: See my suggested solution above for a single line, fully-regex implementation of the same idea.

Comment: Yes, there is such a regex, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58548812/3832970)

Answer (score 0):

I found an incantation that works. It's not pretty:

```
gsub("\\\\autocites[^ ]*",
  gsub("\\}\\{",",",
    gsub(".*(\\\\autocites[^ ]*).*","\\\\\\1",testcase) #all those extra backslashes are there because R is ridiculous.
    ),
  testcase)
```

I broke it in to lines to hopefully make it a little more intelligible. Basically, the innermost `gsub` extracts just the autocites (anything that follows `\\autocites` up to the first space), then the middle `gsub` replaces the `}{`s with commas, and the outermost `gsub` replaces the result of the middle one for the pattern extracted in the innermost one.

This will only work with a single autocites in a string, of course.

Also, `fortune(365)`.

Comment: Your solution looks great. Testing it with the real data set, I found I actually have elements with more than one '\\autocites'. Sorry for the imprecise testcase.